# getResult returns another result than SQL query Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Need just to join to a Member the first uploaded to his gallery Image, but have a big problem as I'm new to symfony.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `member` (
`member_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `image` (
`image_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`member_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`path` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`image_id`),
KEY `image_member_id_idx` (`member_id`),
CONSTRAINT `image_member_id` FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) REFERENCES `member` (`member_id`)             ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Action:

```
$items = $this->getDoctrine()
              ->getManager()
              ->getRepository('AcmeMyBundle:Member')
              ->createQueryBuilder('m')
              ->select('m','i')
              ->leftJoin('Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Image', 'i', 'WITH','i.memberId = m.memberId')
              ->addGroupBy('m.memberId')
              ->setMaxResults(10)
              ->getQuery()
              ->getArrayResult();
```

it returns 2 times more then records in database instead of limit and grouping settings
when I'm printing just `->getQuery->getSQL()` it returns

```
SELECT m0_.member_id AS member_id0, 
m0_.name AS name1, 
i1_.image_id AS image_id2, 
i1_.path AS path3, 
i1_.member_id AS member_id4 
FROM member m0_ 
LEFT JOIN image i1_ 
ON (i1_.member_id = m0_.member_id) 
GROUP BY m0_.member_id LIMIT 10
```

And this query returns right answer on executing it straight from database.
I need help where mistake can be?

Answer (score 0):

If you have properly mapped OneToMany relation you should not explicitly join using columns like:

```
->leftJoin('Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Image', 'i', 'WITH','i.memberId = m.memberId')
```

but rather:

```
->leftJoin('Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Image', 'i')
```

Can you show us your entities?

Also, have you considered using `->getResult()` (object hydration) instead?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

In my case there are duplicated id (is a view in db), so when doctrine populate the objects only create one object for each duplicated row.

I have added a distinct for the target entity ('entityAlias') to get in both cases the same response.

`$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('entityAlias');
 $queryBuilder->leftJoin(...)
->distinct('entityAlias');`

That fix the issue for me.